# Java application connect in the same database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have created two application in Java and that i want to connect them in the same database. Can anyone help me with code example?

```
import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class LidhjaMeSQL {
        Connection connection=null;

    public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        //struktura e kontrollit try-catch
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","root","");
            return connection;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two programs you want to connect to the same database at the same time? What's the problem?

Comment: Yes i want to connect two application in the same database but Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  gives me error.

Comment: What error do you get? I need details. We can't guess what's happening

Comment: It gives ClassNotFoundException in JOptionPane.

Comment: What line number is the error and what does that line say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class LidhjaMeSQL {
    public Connection connectDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "root", "");
            return connection;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            //handle exception here..
        }
    }
}
```

Now in go to the `class` where you want to open the connection. Simply create a new `instance` of `LidhjaMeSQL` and call `connectDB()`.